# Rainfall raster with spline in R

Tags: raster, r, interpolation, spline

I need to create a rainfall raster with cubic spline in R, but I don't know what to do.I have precipitation heights and coordinates of the point where they are measured. Can anyone help me?I tried with Tps function but I need to insert: tension type, weight=0.4 and neighbors=5.

```
library(gstat)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(fields)
setwd("C:/Users/B/Desktop/DatiPrecipitazioni/dati")
mydata<-read.csv(file="2016_01.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",dec=".",na="")
DTM=raster("Dtm1.tif")
crs(DTM) <-"+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9996 +x_0=2520000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-104.1,-49.1,-9.9,0.971,-2.917,0.714,-11.68 +units=m +no_defs"
coordinates(mydata)= ~x+y
m<-Tps(coordinates(mydata),mydata$HPrec)
tps<-interpolate(DTM,m)
tps<-mask(tps,DTM)
contorno=readOGR(dsn="C:/Users/B/Desktop/Tutelacquecal/Base",
layer="griglia_idrologico")
tps<-mask(tps,contorno)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?raster::interpolate` (the examples show the use of thin plate splines).

There are additional interpolation examples at rspatial.org, including a thin plate spline example towards the end of this page:  http://www.rspatial.org/analysis/rst/4-interpolation.html

Based on those examples you can perhaps rephrase your question.